# References in Rails using custom Name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

So I am developing a rails app that will have two kinds of Users, student/tutor. but I only have one User model (using cancan for auth), so when I try to set up the meeting model (which has one tutor and one student) how do I do this? This is the model:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :tutor
  attr_accessible :price, :subject, :time
end
```

and here's the relevant part of the schema:

```
  create_table "meetings", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.integer  "tutor_id"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "meetings", ["student_id"], :name => "index_meetings_on_student_id"
  add_index "meetings", ["tutor_id"], :name => "index_meetings_on_tutor_id"
```

Without having to have two extra models containing student and tutor can I use those labels?

Comment: If you're not very far into the project, I'd consider making tutors and students separate models. It might make things much easier in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do it..

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs to :student, class_name: 'User'
  belongs to :tutor, class_name: 'User'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meet_with_students, class_name: 'Meeting', foreign_key: :tutor_id
  has_many :students, through: :meet_with_students, source: :student
  has_many :meet_with_tutors, class_name: 'Meeting', foreign_key: :student_id
  has_many :tutors, through: :meet_with_tutors:, source: :tutor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `class_name`:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :tutor, class_name: "User"
end
```